# what is difference between cli and mono in unix

Tags: c#, unix, mono

If I start the application directly

```
./coolappimade.exe
```

it get started using /usr/bin/cli. What is difference between this and /usr/bin/mono if any? What is better, start is as "native" or using mono?

Comment: Are you sure `cli` isn't just an alias for `mono`?  It doesn't show up on their list [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Command-Line_Tools).

Answer (score 0):

As Bobson suggested, it is a symlink, I forgot to check...

So:

```
$ which cli
/usr/bin/cli
$ which mono
/usr/bin/mono
$ ls -l /usr/bin/mono
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3054984 Jul 24  2012 /usr/bin/mono
$ ls -l /usr/bin/cli
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr 17 16:16 /usr/bin/cli -> /etc/alternatives/cli
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/cli
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 17 16:16 /etc/alternatives/cli -> /usr/bin/mono
```

Therefore on first sight, there is no difference (this is default way how it is installed in ubuntu). After reading http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications I figured out that the reason why this happens is that the debian packages of mono are registering the .exe as non-native binaries, that are executed using /usr/bin/cli (which is symlink to another symlink to /usr/bin/mono - why is that instead of directly running mono - nobody knows :)). This is just another way to execute mono binaries - according to linked page it's not recommended because it's linux only